# Get PHP file contents and apply variables

Tags: php, variables, include

I'm trying to figure out a way of including a php file as a string, and then applying any variables to it, although I'm not sure exactly how to do that.

In my current MVC workflow my view loader function looks like this:

```
public function view($path, $data=null) {
    if (is_array($data)) extract($data);
    if (file_exists($path)) include ($path);
}
```

So I basically extract an array of variables which are passed from the controller and include the php page, which applies the variables.

However, I have a HTML formatter which I'd like to use to format the page before outputting it. So I want to do something like this:

```
   public function view($path, $data=null) {
        if (is_array($data)) extract($data);
        if (file_exists($path)) echo $formatter->format(file_get_contents($path));
    }
```

The problem here is `file_get_contents` just reads the file as a string, ignoring any php.

How could I get the file content, apply variables to php, then output it through the formatter?

Also, the formatter just formats a string of HTML and returns it as a formatted string.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is use `eval` but I don't think I'd recommend it. Other things being `include`/`require`? Or use both `file_get_contents` and `include`/`require`?

Comment: Include/require will just dump the HTML into the page, I need to store it as string, then apply variables, then dump through formatter. Not sure if this is actually possible,

Comment: Use PHP Tokenizer, you will get what ever you want from it through parsing

Comment: What are you trying to get from that file

Comment: I was thinking of using a preg match of ("<?php / ?>") and pass it through to a string programatically while applying relative variables, then format the whole string, although this could be slow, and also not very reliable.

Comment: check this http://runnable.com/UmkzFYZqrHEnAAAL/how-to-use-token_get_all-with-php-tokenizer

Comment: @zan Can you do a snippet example of how I would use it to parse the php? Also is it realistic in terms of performance?